# Excel: Is it possible and if so, how can i change the applied color rule for a cell, based on 1 or maybe even 2 choices in selection boxes

Tags: excel, colors, multipleselection

im not sure, if this is the right platform to ask this, but maybe someone can help me.

TLDR Question: is it possible and if so, how do i change the color of a cell, based on my either 1 or 2 choices in 2 different, external selection boxes. The first box is supposed to apply for the entire row, while the second one is an individual one for each value in mentioned row (this is the more important one to me, even tho there might be no conceptual difference if we´re talking about just one selection box)

(feel free to tell me about grammatical and other errors if you can find some, id like to improve my english as a none native)

So I´ve started to train a specific mechanic in a game (league of legends) called csing. this means how many creeps i have scored. i am a very visual human so im trying to make this as informative as possible for myself, by highlighting how good a score in my 10 minute timeframe is, based on the character ive played and on the mehtod ive used to cs, mainly if ive used abilities or not (but this is secondary). F.e. on Champion A getting a score of 100 (from 107) is decent, but not really good, while on Champion B 100  of 107 is incredibly good.

For now, I´ve gotten so far to make the cells automatically change color based on fixed numbers, which was enough at the start, since i just played 1 champion with the same method. But as ive played multiple Champions I´ve decided to train this mechanic for selected champions and while the scores i achieve maybe good, they dont accurately depict their actual value. So my aim is to either create a table, which has 3 rows for 3 methods and x columns for x champions with a defined goal scores, which would then be invoked in the rules, or jsut straight up define those numbers for each selection in the ruledefinition.

Thank You in advance for any feedback and answers.

[How my Table looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vGqU.png)

Comment: Have you considered conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Some VBA code I've used that may help you.
Work out your own If Then statements and RGB values.

To set a cell's color:

```
Sub Set_Color(rw, cl)
'
' Set_Color Macro
'

'

    Cells(rw, cl).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0.5
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.5
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

To clear a cell's color:

```
Sub Clear_Color(rw, cl)
'
' Clear_Color Macro
'

'
    Cells(rw, cl).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```